# Apache mod_proxy: forward secure websocket to non-secure

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-proxy, websocket

The websocket library I rely on ([PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)) does not yet support secure sockets (`wss`). My website is served over `https` though, so I cannot use insecure `ws` connections.

I'm trying to use [Apache's `mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) to forward the secure request that comes from the browser on to the client.

**Javascript**

```
var ws = new Websocket('wss://example.com/_ws_/');
```

**Apache VirtualHosts**

```
ProxyPass        "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
# I've also tried "/_ws_/" "ws://example.com:8080/"  Same error below
```

Upon trying to connect, the browser receives a `500 Server Error`. The logs show:

> No protocol handler was valid for the URL /_ws_/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

I've confirmed that if I remove the proxy rules, stop redirecting users to `https` and try to connect to insecure sockets from the browser: `new Websocket('ws://example.com/')`, things work just fine.

My loaded Apache modules include `mod_ssl.c`, `mod_proxy.c` and `mod_proxy_http.c`

`Apache 2.4`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get things to work, I also needed to load [`mod_proxy_wstunnel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

Once I did, this ruleset got things working: (in the `VirtualHost` of the domain that receives and proxies the websocket request)

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
</IfModule>
```

The browser can then contact the backend WS server through the HTTPS port:

```
var ws = new Websocket('wss://example.com/_ws_/');
```

Comment: How should this be applied if the socket url is of this format?
ws://127.0.0.1:8080/script.php

Answer (score 1):

My rep did not give me enough permission to upvote an upper comment, I really struggled to find the best answer so it is and I will share a complete example maybe it will be helpful for some of you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot THEPATHGOESHERE/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory THEPATHGOESHERE/>
      AllowOverride All
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName yourdomain.com
      DocumentRoot THEPATHGOESHERE/public
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      <Directory THEPATHGOESHERE/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
      </Directory>

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
          ProxyPass "/connection/websocket" "ws://yourdomain.com:8088/connection/websocket"
          ProxyPassReverse "/connection/websocket" "ws://yourdomain.com:8088/connection/websocket"
      </IfModule>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're not loading the [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel) module. It's required for reverse proxying WebSocket connections.